# How can I use a counting loop to calculate multiples of a number?

Tags: c, loops, counter, multiplication

I am working on some homework and my task is to write a program in C that uses a loop that counts from 1 to 10 and use the counter of that loop to calculate the multiples up to 5. I have the counting loop created that correctly counts to 10, but where I am stuck at the moment is on the second part of the task. I attempted to create a new loop, but it's not working the way that I would like it to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int counter = 1;

    // heading
    puts("Number\t 1st\t 2nd\t 3rd\t 4th\t 5th");

    // loop that counts to 10
    while (counter <= 10) {
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        counter++; // adds +1 to the counter
    }

    // stuck on this part
    // loop that attempts to take the 10 numbers from prior loop and display their multiples up to 5 times
    while (counter <=10) {
        printf("%d", counter);

        counter = counter * 1;
        counter = counter * 2;
        counter = counter * 3;
        counter = counter * 4;
        counter = counter * 5;
    }
}
```

This is what I am wanting it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do this:

```
    printf("%d", counter);

    counter = counter * 1;
    counter = counter * 2;
    counter = counter * 3;
    counter = counter * 4;
    counter = counter * 5;
```

You're multiplying your counter by `1*2*3*4*5 = 120` every iteration! Instead, you want to keep your counter simply going `1, 2, 3, ...` and directly print the multiples:

```
int counter = 1;

while (counter <= 10) {
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\n",
           counter * 1,
           counter * 1,
           counter * 2,
           counter * 3,
           counter * 4,
           counter * 5);

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, I follow you. Instead of creating another loop, I just needed to print the numbers equal to the same amount that I placed in my heading so that they will count and multiply simultaneously. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For more information, if you want to put a loop inside another loop you can do like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   printf("Number\t1st\t2nd\t3rd\t4th\t5th\n");
   for (int rows = 1; rows <= 10; rows++) {
     printf("%d", rows);
     for(int cols = 1; cols <= 5; cols++) {
         printf("\t%d", rows * cols);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;

} // main
```

But for your purpose, the selected answer is better!

Comment: Wouldn't  `for` loop be better

Comment: @EdHeal I am not sure. We have not covered `for` loops quite yet.

Comment: @HungryMoose A for loop simplifies the follow int = 0; while(i < N) {i++; something}; to for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) something

Comment: @dreamcrash I like for two! Thanks!